# Showing that this set is not the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x) = x^2$. Let $\tau$ denote the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$. Define $\tau_f = \{f^{-1}(S) \, | \, S \in \tau\}$. I want to prove that $\tau$ and $\tau_f$ are equivalent.

My intuition tells me that they are not, but I'm struggling to figure what will suffice in demonstrating that the two sets $\tau$ and $\tau_f$ are equivalent.

Would it be enough to show that open intervals are not in $\tau_f$? I see that all elements in $\tau_f$ have the form $(-b,-a) \cup (a,b)$, but I'm not entirely sure where to go from there.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean to assert that two topologies are equivalent?

Comment: "open intervals are not in $\tau_f$" The open intervals $(-a, a)$ are in $\tau_f$, though.

Comment: Show that an open set of $\tau_f$ contains $1$ iff it contains $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $\tau_f$ is not Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Let $O \in \tau_f$ be such that $1 \in O$. So $O = f^{-1}[U]$ for some Euclidean open $U$ and we know that $f(1)=1 \in U$, but then $f(-1) =1 \in U$ as well, so that $-1 \in O$ as well.

This means that we cannot separate $-1$ and $1$ by disjoint open sets, and so $\tau_f$ is not Hausdorff, while $\tau$ (Euclidean topology) is, just like any metric space.